# Merge tag [ruby-on-rails-4-1] into [ruby-on-rails-4.1]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Can you please merge [ruby-on-rails-4-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4-1) into [ruby-on-rails-4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4.1). The former was probably added by mistake once, and people kept using it.

There is currently half discussions using the first tag, and almost half using the second tag. It's currently a common practice to create version tags using dots, this tag is clearly a typo (compared to all the other [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) version tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A synonym was already suggested in the opposite direction, so I swapped it around and merged the two together. Thanks for the suggestion.